# css hml div full height with text rotate on 90° and centered in a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to expand the text to all height of the green div and center it vertical. This is an example: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/alfa90/na89trxh/6/)

HTML:

```
<div class="willSlide" id='content'></div>
<div class="willSlide" id='btn'>
    <span class="click">CLICK THIS IS A VERY VERY  VERY VERY VERY LONG TEXT</span>
    <span class="expandedTxt">Expanded! THIS IS A  VERY VERY VERY LONG TEXT</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    background:rgb(97, 97, 97);
    width:200px;
    right:0px;
    margin-right: -200px;
}
#btn{
position: fixed;
width: 30px;
height: 100%;
right: 0px;
background: rgb(117, 231, 117);
text-align: center;
padding: 40px 0;
cursor:pointer
}
.click{
  display:block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.expandedTxt{
  display:none; 
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
#btn.expanded .expandedTxt{
 display:block   
}
#btn.expanded .click{
 display:none   
}
```

There is also some JQuery for animation...
What is wrong or how to achieve that?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/na89trxh/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the width of the span, once rotated becomes the height and is 30px.  You need to fix the width of the .click and the .expandedTxt to fit the text.  You will also need to translate the span so that the starting point is within your .willslide div.